# Spring @JsonFormat exception handler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, annotations

I'm trying to catch and handle an exception for a invalid field value annotated with  `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.SSS"), but in the RestExceptionHandler` class not taking that exception with any type of Exception, neither with `@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})`.

What type of exception is thrown when `@JsonFormat` validation fails or how can I intercept and handle taht exception?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `@JsonFormat` annotation to validate date format, if the format of the input date string does not match the expected pattern, Jackson will throw a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException` exception.

To handle this exception in your `RestExceptionHandler` class, you can add an `@ExceptionHandler` method that takes specific exception as parameter. For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
 
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidFormatException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleInvalidFormatException(InvalidFormatException ex) {
        // Handle the exception 
    }
 
    // Other exception handling 
}
```

Comment: I've tried with that exception(InvalidFormatException) but the Handler not taking or intercepting the exception. I have a handler for Exception.clkass but nweither with that exception is working.